# Notifying users of new comments in a post

Tags: json, mongodb

I am using MongoDB in my app and I want to notify subscribed users of new comments in a blog post. So this is more or less how my DB looks life:

```
class Post(Document):
    description = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    inserted_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
    author = ReferenceField('User', reverse_delete_rule='CASCADE')
```

So if a user comments in a particular post, whenever a new comment is added to this post, the user should get notified.

I was thinking of having a table called Notifications, with the following document structure:

```
Notifications = [{

  user1 : {

    - unread comment1
    - unread comment2

  },
  user2 : {
   -
   -
  }

  ...

}]
```

Another option is to organize the notifications by comments (since they would be repeating a lot), and then get all users that commented (using the table Post) on the same post where the new comment belongs to.

Each user would have a notification feed and the "events" would be removed from the database once the user mark them as read.

I don't know if I am being very clear. These approaches sound a bit naive to me, so I would really appreciate your opinions and suggestions.

Comment: You might want to store the id of the comment, rather than the comment, in case the writer goes in and edits the original comment. Not sure if you allow that or not. You are replicating a lot of data. You might want to simply have a structure on the user, with a list of unread comments, rather than a whole new table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) storing that information on the user makes sense, but in terms of replicating data, it wouldn't be very different if I create the new table and reference the comment id (where it says unread comment1, and so on), right?

Comment: No, you can do it that way. One thing, if you ever delete a user, you get better data integrity by having that data in the client. If your client delete fails, you could have data left over in the notification table. That's probably not that important, however. Also, if it's on the client table, that record could grow indefinitely, which is a bad thing.